# Why is TypeScript not complaining about returning "any" when implementing a method of an interface?

Tags: typescript, types

Following example, tested with TypeScript 5.2.2 and "use strict"

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgJwPYBMCuBjEMC8MDewMMAzgNZoBcpICAlgHYDmA3ETAwIYC2U1JtRq3YR6GPhzTcARlARsAvsGCMQcgGadx8ZOiwAlKBCQk6IJAjAF2xJlBAAhMAEkUACnJUa9ZgEpqiEjcdCRQADyBeiAAfMBKwBgANpwkJDAAytAYdOp0GJGYIIbGpuaWMHTcEIlQvAwgaQUGRiZmFlaENjApYAwYMHaOLu4AjmhyYPyCftZdxMQYSAwCMOr2GAAWUCgAYsjcACLSuAQK3WmcDGBsc-MI9mgIDKvrW7v7R2zzMPEKQA)

```
type Product = {
  sku: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

interface ProductRepository {
    getById(sku: string): Promise<Product>
}

class SpecificProductRepository implements ProductRepository {

    async getById(query: string) {

        const fetchedFromDb = {} as any;

        return fetchedFromDb;
    }

}
```

I would expect TypeScript to complain that getById is not returning `Promise<Product>` but it does not. If I try to return something specific like `"foo"` it shows an error. Same for `unknown`.

I tried to implement the interface with an object instead of a class and it shows the same behavior.

```
const anotherProductRepository: ProductRepository = {

  async getById(query: string) {
    
      const fetchedFromDb = {} as any;

      return fetchedFromDb;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Alex - Looks like this is covered by previous questions and answers, so I've removed mine below. The gist of it is that that's just how [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) works, it can be assigned to any other type. It also suggested you might want to use [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) instead, but you commented saying the `any` is coming from a library, not your code.

Comment: @​Alex - Re the question you asked in a comment on my deleted answer: *"Thank you, I did the `as any` part to illustrate a complex query to a db which returns `any` as as a result if the return type is not further specified. E.g. building a query with knex.js which returns `any`. So it would actually be better behavior by knex.js to return `unknown`?"*  "Better" is a value judgement I doubt I have sufficient expertise to make. :-) It would have helped you here, though, since it requires an explicit type assertion or contextual narrowing before it can be assigned to something else. But...

Comment: ...`unknown` is relatively new, so that may be a factor in why knex is using `any`. (Perhaps someone tangential, but: If you need to validate the values you're getting back, you might look at things like [zod](https://zod.dev), which handles both the actual validation and the type assertion. [There are others as well.]) HTH!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, thanks a lot. Too bad this question was marked as duplicate and you removed the answer, it summarized this case quite well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to undelete my answer and mark it "community wiki" if you like.